# Unable to fully collect metrics, when installing metric-server

Tags: kubernetes

I have installed the metric server on kubernetes, but its not working and logs

```
unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:xxx: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet ... (X.X): Get https:....: x509: cannot validate certificate for 1x.x.

x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

I was able to get metrics if modified the deployment yaml and added

```
 command:
        - /metrics-server
        - --kubelet-insecure-tls
        - --kubelet-preferred-address-types=InternalIP
```

this now collects metrics, and  kubectl top node returns results...

but logs still show

```
 E1120 11:58:45.624974       1 reststorage.go:144] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod dev/pod-6bffbb9769-6z6qz: no metrics known for pod
E1120 11:58:45.625289       1 reststorage.go:144] unable to fetch pod metrics for pod dev/pod-6bffbb9769-rzvfj: no metrics known for pod
E1120 12:00:06.462505       1 manager.go:102] unable to fully collect metrics: [unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:ip-1x.x.x.eu-west-1.compute.internal: unable to get CPU for container ...discarding data: missing cpu usage metric, unable to fully scrape metrics from source
```

so questions

1) All this works on minikube, but not on my dev cluster, why would that be?

2) In production i dont want to do insecure-tls.. so can someone please explain why this issue is arising... or point me to some resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubeadm generates the kubelet certificate at `/var/lib/kubelet/pki` and those certificates (`kubelet.crt and kubelet.key`) are signed by different CA from the one which is used to generate all other certificates at `/etc/kubelet/pki`.

You need to regenerate the kubelet certificates which is signed by your root CA (`/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt`)

You can use openssl or cfssl to generate the new certificates(I am using cfssl)

```
$ mkdir certs; cd certs
$ cp /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt ca.pem
$ cp /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.key ca-key.pem
```

Create a file `kubelet-csr.json`:

```
{
  "CN": "kubernetes",
  "hosts": [
    "127.0.0.1",
    "<node_name>",
    "kubernetes",
    "kubernetes.default",
    "kubernetes.default.svc",
    "kubernetes.default.svc.cluster",
    "kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"
  ],
  "key": {
    "algo": "rsa",
    "size": 2048
  },
  "names": [{
    "C": "US",
    "ST": "NY",
    "L": "City",
    "O": "Org",
    "OU": "Unit"
  }]
}
```

Create a ca-config.json file:

```
{
  "signing": {
    "default": {
      "expiry": "8760h"
    },
    "profiles": {
      "kubernetes": {
        "usages": [
          "signing",
          "key encipherment",
          "server auth",
          "client auth"
        ],
        "expiry": "8760h"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now generate the new certificates using above files:

```
$ cfssl gencert -ca=ca.pem -ca-key=ca-key.pem \
--config=ca-config.json -profile=kubernetes \
kubelet-csr.json | cfssljson -bare kubelet
```

Replace the old certificates with newly generated one:

```
$ scp kubelet.pem <nodeip>:/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt
$ scp kubelet-key.pem <nodeip>:/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.key
```

Now restart the kubelet so that new certificates will take effect on your node.

```
$ systemctl restart kubelet
```

Look at the following tickets to get the context of issue:

https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/metrics-server/issues/146

Hope this helps.

Comment: do i need to ssh onto my cluster? and execute these commands... these are not done via kubectl?

Comment: Yes you need to login to your master node and generate those certificates by following the steps. No, there is no need of kubectl  commands as we are generating certificates only.

Comment: Thanks... and so if i have two masters... do i need to do that on both?

Comment: Yes you need to replace the kubelet.crt and kubelet.key on all the nodes. Keep in mind you need to generate the new certs for each, changing the `node_name` in `kubelet_csr.json` file and repeat those steps.

Comment: you're welcome :) There is one open defect with kubernetes around this. Have a look here https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1223

Comment: Hi, i further looked into this, if you could clarify please, i understand the need for certificates. However kubadm should have generated these, correct? And my pods are being deployed to the nodes.

Comment: Yes, kubeadm should have handled the generation of kubelet cert with different CA, but currently it is not and hence you're facing issue collecting metrics. This is an open issue with kubernetes (link mentioned in my answer) and it will be fixed (hopefully) in future release. As of now, this is the issue present and I have mentioned the workaround/solution for it.

Comment: okay makes sense.... so what is the apiserver-kubelet-client.key and apiserver-kubelet-client.crt on master used for?.. I appreciate your help. Im just getting familiar with the internals of kubernetes.

Comment: apiserver-kubelet-client.crt is used for secure communication between the apiserver and the kubelet inside the Master. This is a very nice blog to understand how k8s certificate works: https://jvns.ca/blog/2017/08/05/how-kubernetes-certificates-work/